# Creating class and passing content

Tags: android, class, typeface

I made a method where all the font's get changed, but the problem is that I want to use the method once so I don't have to copy and paste it in every script.

Code example:

```
public void changeFont(){

    int[] id_et = {R.id.inputObjectName, R.id.inputObjectValue};
    int[] id_tv = {R.id.headerUserInfo, R.id.headerUserPW, R.id.headerUserGW};
    int[] id_btn = {R.id.privBtnIncome, R.id.privBtnExpense};

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Sanford.TTF");

    for(int i = 0; i < id_et.length; i++){
        EditText textbox = (EditText) findViewById(id_et[i]);
        textbox.setTypeface(font);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < id_tv.length; i++){
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(id_tv[i]);
        tv.setTypeface(font);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < id_btn.length; i++){
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(id_btn[i]);
        btn.setTypeface(font);
    }

}
```

When I create a class and make an object to use the constructor to get the data, the program crashes.

This is how the class looks:

```
public class ChangeFont extends Activity{
    public ChangeFont(){

    int[] id_et = {R.id.inputObjectName, R.id.inputObjectValue};
    int[] id_tv = {R.id.headerUserInfo, R.id.headerUserPW, R.id.headerUserGW};
    int[] id_btn = {R.id.privBtnIncome, R.id.privBtnExpense};

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Sanford.TTF");

    for(int i = 0; i < id_et.length; i++){
        EditText textbox = (EditText) findViewById(id_et[i]);
        textbox.setTypeface(font);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < id_tv.length; i++){
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(id_tv[i]);
        tv.setTypeface(font);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < id_btn.length; i++){
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(id_btn[i]);
        btn.setTypeface(font);
    }

    }

}
```

Error log:

```
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{united.aristal.freewallet/united.aristal.freewallet.PrivateWallet}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:75)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at united.aristal.freewallet.ChangeFont.<init>(ChangeFont.java:16)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at united.aristal.freewallet.PrivateWallet.onCreate(PrivateWallet.java:32)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
12-12 17:23:49.746: E/AndroidRuntime(6159):     ... 11 more
```

So can anyone help me here?

Comment: you can call getAssets() after super.onCreate() in your overloaded onCreate()  ... only then activity is fully initiated ... move your code to onCreate()

Comment: you've added logcat log .... and it is telling exactly what i've wrote ... in constructor (<init>) Context is not fully created and you need the Context to getAssests ...

Comment: How do you use the getAssets() method? I've pasted everything to onCreate(). Still searching for examples...

Comment: it depends on your needs ... if you wana build base class which extends Activity you should move all this code to onCreate(Bundle) or ... leave it as is but you should changename of class ... with this name and this class name this function is not a normal funcition but it's a constructor ... but still you should remeber that ChangeFont() should be called after onCreate ...

Comment: "but you should changename of class ... with this name and this class name this function is not a normal funcition but it's a constructor." Can you give me an example?

Comment: sure `public class ClassName /*this is class name*/ { public ClassName() { /*this is constructor*/} public void justOrdinaryMethod() { /* this is method, name should be different from class name(ClassName in this case) */} }` .... so first read about java basics and then read whole dev guide from http://developer.android.com ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAssets` is throwing `NullPointerException` because you created the `ChangeFont` instance instead of letting Android do it. If `ChangeFont` is just a utility class, it should not extend `Activity`.

Instead, initialize it with an instance of your actual activity, and let it call methods on that activity.

```
public class ChangeFont {

    public ChangeFont(final Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "Sanford.TTF");
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I create an instance of my actual activity? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Is this what you mean:
    cf = new ChangeFont(activity);

Comment: Correct, your `PrivateWallet` activity would call that in its `onCreate` method.